# Auto Submit Barcode Scanner

Tags: php, html

I have this code for search in my database, I use a  barcode scanner (work like a keyboard), when I scan a barcode the input text shown perfectly, but I need to press MATCH to do the enter function, I want to submit it automatically after the barcode scanner scan a code and not to press MATCH.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container pt-5">

        <div class="row">
            
            <form method="POST" action="match.php" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Scan:</label>
            <input type="text" id="no" name="no" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div ></div>
            <button class="btn btn-info" name="sub" type="submit">MATCH</button>

            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
include 'includes/conn.php';

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $sca=trim($_POST['no'],"");     
    $flag=0;
    $credentials="";
    $password="";
    $firstname="";
    $lastname="";
    $new2 ="SELECT * FROM `voters`";
    $res2=mysqli_query($conn, $new2);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
        //echo $row['number'].'<br>';
     // if($row['number']){
                  if($row['credentials'] == $sca){
                    $flag=1;
                    $credentials=$row['credentials'];
                    $password=$row['password'];
                    $firstname=$row['firstname'];
                    $lastname=$row['lastname'];
                  }

        
   }if ($flag==1) {
        echo    "<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3'></div><div class='col-sm-6'><div class='alert alert-success d-flex justify-content-center mt-3'>".

                  '<br><b>Votante:</b>'.' '.$id.
                  '<br><b>Registro:</b>'.' '.$credentials.
                  '<br><b>Contraseña:</b>'.' '.$password.
                  '<br><b>Nombre:</b>'.' '.$firstname.
                  '<br><b>Apellidos:</b>'.' '.$lastname.
                  
                  "</div></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3'></div><div class='col-sm-6'>" ;
                    return;
   }
   else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center mt-3'>Product Not Found</div></div>";    
                return;
            }
    
}
mysqli_close($conn);
 
?>
```

Comment: You'll need to start by giving us some details, as to what _"after the barcode scanner scan a product"_ actually means. We don't currently know how it interacts with your form at all.

Comment: I edit the message and include the full code

Comment: The whole server-side part of how you are processing this _after_ it was submitted, is pretty irrelevant. _"when I scan a barcode the input text shown perfectly"_ - we need to know how _that_ part happens, how the scanner interacts with your form. We don't know _how_ it puts the value into the form field. You might try a `change` or `input` handler for that field - but if the value is written into the field via JavaScript, those won't trigger. You might need something like an interval that regularly checks whether the current field value has changed then.

Comment: I notice the barcode scanner work like keyboard, I think I need something like submit after type 5 numbers (numbers  qty that I use)

Comment: Add an `input` handler then, inside read the current value, and if the length of that is 5 characters - submit the form, or make an AJAX request.

Comment: First of all the backend-part is completely irrelevant here. Typically Barcode scanner are just like HID-Keyboards so there is no difference whether a human types the value in or one scans a code.
As @CBroe mentioned you can write an input handler which reacts to all value changes in the input field. As a beginner you may want to use jQuery. When the code reaches a specific (?) length, you can proceed by trigger a submission process.

Answer (score 0):

We had to work with barcode scanners a while ago, where we had a similar request, so I hope I can help here. Most simple barcode scanners just enter the scanned code and append a new line.

As stated in the comments you need some JavaScript in order to do that. We used the [jquery](https://jquery.com/) library. Like CBroe said, you need to find the correct event, to use. We tried different events and found the "change" event to be the best suitable one for us.

Our case was a little more complex, because we had multiple fields and had to make ajax requests, so I tried to reduce our script to something that may be a good starting point for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#no').change(function () { //if content of field with id #no changes do stuff
        let value = $(this).val();
        const minlength = 5;
        if (value.length >= minlength) {
            $( "#scanform" ).submit(); //submit form with id scanform
        }
    });
});
```

Pleas note, that this script assumes you add the id "scanform" to your form tag.